# Calculus 3- Line Integrals

Tags: calculus

Evaluate the line integral, where $C$ is the given curve, $\int_C \sin(x)\,dx + cos(y)\,dy$. $C$ consists of the top half of the circle $x^2 + y^2 = 16$ from $(4, 0)$ to $(-4, 0)$ and the line segment from $(-4, 0)$ to $(-5, 3)$.

I know I need to split this up into two integrals. My main concern about this is how to integrate the top half of the circle. I do not know if I need to set my $x$ and $y$ into $4\sin t$ and $4\cos t$ or leave it as it is, but overall do not know how to set up the two integrals. Any help on how to start this would be great. Thanks.

Comment: It  seems greens theorem yields $0$

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, one has that the line integral over the path $C$ is the sum of the line integrals over $C_1$ and $C_2$, where the former path is the semicircle and the latter the line segment. We begin with the evaluation of the line integral over $C_1$. We parameterise $C_1$ by

$$C_1(t)=(4\cos t, 4\sin t), \qquad 0\leq t \leq \pi.$$

This yields

$$\int\limits_{C_1} \sin x \; dx + \cos y \; dy = -\int\limits_0^{\pi} 4\sin(4\cos t)\sin t \; dt + \int\limits_0^{\pi} 4\cos(4\sin t) \cos t \; dt = 0,$$

where both of the integrals evaluate to zero. (I leave this to be shown true by the reader). The parameterisation of $C_2$ is given by

$$C_2(t)=(-4-t,3t) \qquad 0\leq t \leq 1,$$

however I also leave this to the consideration of the reader.